# Cambiar la primera letra de una valor

Tags: c#

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es cambiar la primera letra de un string por una M. No quiero cambiar el nombre por completo porque no me serviria para lo que estoy haciendo. Ejemplo: tengo una variable llamada "E3" y necesito cambiarla a "M3". No tengo idea de por donde comenzar tampoco.

```
string carta = "O4";
```

Comment: Tú dices esto: `carta = "M" + carta[1..];` ???

Comment: Si si es eso muchisimas gracias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Un String es inmutable, lo que quiere decir que no es posible cambiar su valor. Lo que se puede hacer es modificar la variable `carta` por un nuevo valor (que son cosas distintas).

Para esto puedes usar [Rangos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/ranges-indexes) y hacer algo como:

```
string carta = "O4";
carta = "M" + carta[1..];
```

Donde `carta[1..]` es un substring que comienza desde la posición `1` hasta el final (es lo mismo que `carta[1..carta.Length]`)

Answer (score 4):

Puedes borrar el primer carácter del string y posteriormente anteponer al string el valor deseado:

```
carta = carta.Remove(0, 1);
carta = "M" + carta;
```

Comment: Cómo es que el OP había aceptado la primera respuesta? me interesa saber...

Comment: @Yussef cierto, una pequeña pifia, ya cambie la respuesta, gracias

Comment: @Excorpion no tengo idea de pq lo hizo, igual ya arreglé mi respuesta, me equivoqué garrafalmente en mi respuesta original disculpa a todos

Comment: Me parece justo que la respuesta de @Yussef sea la aceptada, el tiene además mi voto

Answer (score 4):

Solo para agregar otra respuesta, se podia hacer tambien con [Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-8.0) que funciona en cualquier version de .net...

```
carta = "M" + carta.Substring(1);
```